# Backup files and folders on Windows server to NAS

Tags: backup, sftp, windows-server, winscp, synology

I'm looking to backup files and folders on a Windows server to a Synology NAS over the internet once every night. I only want the new and changed files/folders however, I don't want to be transferring everything every night.

The current way I'm thinking of doing this is by running a WinSCP command in the Windows Task Scheduler that SFTP transfers any necessary files and folders.

I'd like to know if I'm heading in the right direction, if not what should I be doing instead, if I am what WinSCP command will do what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, WinSCP can do this. Just, [create a synchronization batch file](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation) like:

```
@echo off

"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" ^
  /log="C:\writable\path\to\log\Backup.log" /ini=nul ^
  /command ^
    "open sftp://username:password@mynas/ -hostkey=""ssh-rsa ...""" ^
    "synchronize remote C:\Users\username\Documents /backup" ^
    "exit"
```

And then [schedule the batch file to be executed](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_schedule) as you need.

The example is for SFTP. If your NAS supports FTP(S), you can use that too.

[WinSCP GUI can generate a batch file](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_generateurl#script) like above for you (except for the [`synchronize` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_synchronize) part).

Comment: Sorry it's been a while, I've been busy with other stuff. I've got the code working now (albeit without the /ini=nul until I work out how to use host keys) so thanks.